# Elasticsearch sort on aggregations filter

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Is there any way to sort on *filter aggregation* ?

```
GET item_*/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "page_id": [
                            1,
                            652, ...
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group1": {
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "page_id": [
                        1,
                        652,...
                    ]
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "sum_items_likes": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "reactions.likes"
                    }
                }, ...
            }
        },
        "group2": ...
    }
}
```

I would like to sort by "aggregations.groupX.sum_items_likes"

I take this opportunity to ask if it's worth pre-filtering *page_id* before aggregation

Thank you for your help